# The Specified Object or Value Does not Exist

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, raspberry-pi3, windowsiot

I have developed a UWP application that capture video from web cam and saves to local storage of UWP and the application works perfectly fine on local machine however after deploying it on RaspberryPi3 I am getting the fo

> The Specified Object or Value Does not Exist

Files are being saved to localData of Application. After debugging I got to know the error is in following lines:

```
MediaEncodingProfile recordProfile = null;
recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWmv(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);

await _mediaCapture.StartRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile, recordStorageFile);
_statuses.Add(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ": " + fileName + " Recording in progress");
```

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

> [The issue maybe due to your USB camera has no micro phone,  but the
>   default capture mode is video and audio.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/8ec27e02-4323-49e8-8c77-5e4aaaa007f4/exception-when-calling-startrecordtostoragefileasync-win10-iotminnowboard-max?forum=WindowsIoT)

So, before calling MediaCapture.InitializeAsync() you need set the StreamingCaptureMode to Video like this:

```
            var settings = new Windows.Media.Capture.MediaCaptureInitializationSettings();
            settings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.Audio;
            await mediaCapture.InitializeAsync(settings);
```

Comment: I had similar issue.... setting the streaming capture mode to video worked for me :                                                                settings.StreamingCaptureMode = Windows.Media.Capture.StreamingCaptureMode.Video;                            Thanks